# HeaderViewListAdapter randomly crashes

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am getting random crash in crashlytics and I can not simulate it. It crashes randomly both on Android V2 and V4 but **very very rarely**:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
   at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:225)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1498)
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1749)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1294)
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1349)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:801)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1263)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1137)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1051)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:342)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7320)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1162)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1882)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

**Invalid index 3, size is 0** - indexes are Random in crashlytics.
I am using ListView with header and footer in fragment.

In **onCreateView**:

```
mSearchBox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_box, mListView, false);
mListView.addHeaderView(mSearchBox, null, false);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I use header in ListView for EditText for searching in ListView (purposely because I want that EditText is scrollable with listview content). And also I use addFooterView for showing loader (when loading next items in list).

You can look at HeaderViewListAdapter line 225 ([GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java/#224)):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// ...
// ... code
// ...

// Footer (off-limits positions will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException)
return mFooterViewInfos.get(adjPosition - adapterCount).view;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I have found similiar stackoverflow thread but It is not helpful for me:  [Indexoutofboundsexception with listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950069/indexoutofboundsexception-with-listview)
Looks like android ListView is a bit bugged when using header or footer in ListView with fragments.

Comment: I also met this problem, do you have a solution now?

Comment: Updated post, see above.

Comment: @Yuraj.thanks,this looks like works. I  find this problem in my  nexus 5 android 6.0.I also check the source in it was because when use `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView` to add a footer view or a header view ,the Adapter has  changed to
`HeaderViewListAdapter` which has problem.

Comment: @Yuraj post your EDIT as a solution of your question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set null adapter on listview before I was clearing the adapter:

```
mListView.setAdapter(null);
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```