# ListView IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-listview, crash, indexoutofboundsexception

i"m getting crash reports on IndexOutOfBoundsException inside my adapter , it was never happen on my device so i don't know the scenario .

on my getView it crash (itemlist.get(position)):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

Object i = itemlist.get(position);
```

and of course i override getcount , as i mention it was never happen to me but i get reports that is happen to usersaa sometimes

```
public int getCount() {
    return itemlist.size();
}
```

any ideas how could it be ? and how to prevent it ?

Comment: posy your adapter code please !

Answer (score 1):

you should use parent in place of itemlist to get data from list.

```
Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

String text=item.toString();
```

Comment: parent is my ViewGroup  , i didn't really understood the solution .

Answer (score 0):

I solve it . And here is my answer.
[Indexoutofboundsexception with listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950069/indexoutofboundsexception-with-listview/32816621#32816621)

***What you have to do is find out whitch view cause this exception. And make sure once the data changed notify the adapter immediately!***