# How to debug Android java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException HeaderViewListAdapter.java line

Tags: java, android, exception

I have an app which is live in the android playstore, where I recently started seeing crash reports from Crashlytics with the following trace :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
   at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
   at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3259)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4960)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13116)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.draw(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:500)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13116)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13116)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13896)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3024)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2893)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14183)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2449)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1198)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2431)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2303)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2109)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1179)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4859)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

My app has got lots of screens and views, and from this trace there is no frame which is from my app :( How do I figure out where to start looking? Any pointers on this very much appreciated.

Comment: that mean your `ArrayList` or `array` is `empty` whatever you passing in `HeaderViewListAdapter.java`

Comment: Do your analytics report which activity is loaded before that error? Are there a lot of places in your code where you have a HeaderViewListAdapter?

Comment: Your `HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled` method is throwing the exception by not checking if its analyzing a correct index of the given array. Add some checks to make sure its a valid index value

Comment: Did you got any solution for the issue? I am also facing the same issue and not able to find any solution for it.

Comment: getting the same issue though I have not used any HeaderViewListAdapter

Answer (score 2):

Override `getHeadersCount()` and always return 0 when you data size is 0.

```
@Override
public int getHeadersCount(){
  return getCount() == 0 ? 0 : super.getHeaderCount();
}
```

This happens when you are having non null data list and it attempts to access 0 element.

Also you might need to do the same with `isEnabled()` method

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position){
  return position > 0 || getHeadersCount() > 0 ? super.isEnabled(position) : false;
}
```

Comment: Override where?

Comment: @m0skit0 override in the Adapter. You need to create a class that extends your adapter and overrides this method.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception while using custom adapter with ListView. And exception was thrown from Android standard library classes, not even leading to any line of my code. 
I also was adding Header, so my adapter was implicitly wrapped by HeaderViewListAdapter. 
In my case the problem appears when I'm deleting data from adapter.

I was thinking that the problem is because ListView or adapter can't work fine with Header, but for real the reason was other.

**My solution is to make sure that adapter's data is never changed from other threads, and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called from UI thread.**

So, after fixes everything works and my code looks like:

```
// Loader's callbacks
@Override
public Loader<...> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new Loader...
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<...> loader, Data data) {
    ...
    // adapter's list of items
    listItems.clear();
    listItems.addAll(data);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ...
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> loader) {
    ...
}

// custom loader 
private static class ContactAsyncLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<...> {
    @Override
    public List<..> loadInBackground() {
        Data data = new ..
        ...
        return data;
    }
}
```